# SQL- convert varchar yyyymmdd-ttttt to iso 8601 format

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, varchar, iso8601

I am looking for a way to convert `varchar yyyymmdd-ttttt` to `iso 8601` format. Here is an example of the value I am looking to convert:

```
20120503-56320
```

I have already tried:

```
CONVERT(NVARCHAR(30), ia.alcreateStamp, 126)
```

which doesnt not change the format. Thank you in advance.

Beth

Comment: Which programming language are you using? It is impossible to answer you question without knowing that.

Comment: Apologies. SQL. Using SQL server 2012

Comment: Your code does the exact opposite of what you ask. It tries to convert a *date* into a *string*. Besides, storing dates as strings is a bug in itself. What are the *actual* types and what are you really trying to do? Convert one string to another? Why not use the correct types, `datetime` or `datetime2` instead? At least, convert the string value into a datetime?

Comment: what is 56320 equate to?

Comment: What time is `56320`? It's obviously not `5:63:20`. It could be the number of seconds since midnight (making the time `15:38:40`) but that's speculation on my end.

Comment: `56320` doesn't look like any kind of valid time - is the hour `53`? Or the minute `63`? Whatever that format is, it's not `yyyymmdd-ttttt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first problem here is you are storing a datetime as an `(n)varchar`. Store dates, and times, as what they are, a `date`, `time` or `datetime(2)`.

When using `CONVERT` to change the datatype to a `(n)varchar`, providing a style code tells the data engine the format the string should be in from the corresponding datatype (in this case a `date` or `datetime(2)` datatype). You're converting an `nvarchar` to an `nvarchar`, so that style code is completely ignored.

I'm ***guessing*** that the value `20120503-56320` is the date 2012-05-03 15:34:40 (there are 86400 seconds in a day, and I am assuming -56320 is the seconds into the day), thus to convert your value to a `datetime2` you would use:

```
SELECT DateString,
       DATEADD(SECOND,CONVERT(int,RIGHT(V.DateString,LEN(V.DateString) - CI.I)),CONVERT(datetime2(0),LEFT(V.DateString,CI.I -1))),
       CONVERT(varchar(19),DATEADD(SECOND,CONVERT(int,RIGHT(V.DateString,LEN(V.DateString) - CI.I)),CONVERT(datetime2(0),LEFT(V.DateString,CI.I -1))),126)
FROM (VALUES('20120503-56320')) V(DateString)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX('-',V.DateString))) CI(I);
```

Honestly, at this point, you should stop. Pass the `datetime2` value to your presentation layer and handle the formatting there.

If you really want to improve, however, then fix your datatype. One method might be to add a new persisted column:

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable ADD DateValue AS DATEADD(SECOND,CONVERT(int,RIGHT(DateString,LEN(DateString) - CHARINDEX('-',DateString))),CONVERT(datetime2(0),LEFT(DateString,CHARINDEX('-',DateString) -1))) PERSISTED;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately, I only have read access to this database so I must convert in my select statement.

Comment: @brose ideally then you should be talking to whoever designed the database and getting them to fix their poor design choice.

Comment: @brose if you have to though, then wrap the above expression in a further `CONVERT`, as shown above.

Comment: Perfect! I used the code above, stuffed it in a temp table, and pulled it back out with my original code and that did the trick. Not sure if that was the most efficient way to do it, but it worked. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

This assumes that the format is YYYYMMDD- followed by the number of seconds since midnight.

You can construct the value you want by adding seconds to the date value:

```
select dateadd(second, convert(int, right(str, 5)), convert(datetime, left(str, 8)))
from (values ('20120503-56320')) v(str)
```

This assumes that the seconds is zero-padded, so "1" would be "-00001".  If that is not the case, use:

```
select dateadd(second, convert(int, stuff(str, 1, charindex('-', str) , '')), convert(datetime, left(str, 8)))
```

Or (as Jeroen points out):

```
select dateadd(second, convert(int, stuff(str, 1, 9, '')), convert(datetime, left(str, 8)))
```

You can incorporate this directly into the table as a generated column as well:

```
alter table t add alcreateStamp_dt as 
    ( dateadd(second, convert(int, stuff(str, 1, charindex('-', str) , '')), convert(datetime, left(str, 8))) );
```

Then you won't need to replicate the logic each time you want the value as a `datetime`.

Comment: Since we're already assuming the date part has a constant length, `DATEADD(SECOND, CONVERT(INT, STUFF(str, 1, 9, '')), LEFT(str, 8))` would do.